# How to test using Mockito?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing

I am testing for newsapi using mockito but i always get test failed:

```
Testing started at 8:12 PM ...
D:\flutter\flutter_windows_3.3.10-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color test --machine --plain-name "testing http" test\unit_testing\provider_test.dart

test\unit_testing\provider_test.dart 12:7   MockClient.NewArticles
test\unit_testing\provider_test.dart 27:31  main.<fn>.<fn>

type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<List<Article>>'
```

This is my Provider class:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:http/testing.dart';
import 'package:news_app/ApiService.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart'as http;
import 'package:news_app/Article.dart';
abstract class GetApiData {
  Future<List<Article>>NewArticles();
}

class ProviderData extends ChangeNotifier implements GetApiData{

  late Map<String, dynamic>json;

  Future<List<Article>>NewArticles()async{

    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=techcrunch&apiKey=977b53e9e8624f64b649a80c04a656fe'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200){
      json = jsonDecode(response.body);

      List<dynamic>body = json['articles'];

      _articles=body.map((e) => Article.fromJson(e)).toList();

      notifyListeners();
      return _articles;
    }

    else {
      throw('$response.body');
    }
  }
}
```

This is my test code:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:http/testing.dart';
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:news_app/ApiService.dart';
import 'package:news_app/Article.dart';
import 'package:news_app/Provider.dart';
import 'provider_test.mocks.dart';
class MockClient extends Mock implements GetApiData{}



late MockClient newclient;

void main(){
  setUp((){
  newclient=MockClient();
});

group('testing http',() {


  test('test http function',() async {
  var newuser=await newclient.NewArticles();


final articleList=Article.fromJson({"source":{"id":"techcrunch", "name":    "TechCrunch"},
  "author":"Rebecca Bellan",

  "title":"Ford Q1 earnings rebound as trucks and fleet sales drive profits",

  "description":"Ford beat Wall Street revenue expectations of around 36 billion for the quarter with a total revenue of 41.5 billion, up 20% YoY.",

  "url":"https://techcrunch.com/2023/05/02/ford-q1-earnings-rebound-as-trucks-and-fleet-sales-drive-profits/",

  "urlToImage":"https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/Ford-Europe-GettyImages.jpeg?resize=1200,800",

  "publishedAt":"2023-05-02T21:13:12Z",
  
"content":"Ford reported its first quarter 2023 earnings Tuesday after the bell, and it marks the first time the legacy automaker will break down earnings by its three new business units: Ford Blue for the icon… [+3561 chars]"}
 );


  final newurl=await newclient.NewArticles();
  expect(newurl.length,1);

});
}
```

After test failure i tried this also and had the same result

```dart
 test('test http function',() async {
   when(client.get(Uri.parse('https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?domains=wsj.com&apiKey=eac151759e98448f8712913e2028cfd0'))).

thenAnswer((realInvocation)async{
  
 return http.Response('{source:{id:"the-wall-street-journal"},name:"the-wall-street-journal",'
   'author:"wsj",title:"Can Kidney Transplant Drug Keep You From Aging?"'
   ',descriptoin:"Longevity seekers are captivated by a transplant drug called rapamycin, but many doctors are wary",'
   'url:"https://www.wsj.com/articles/rapamycin-anti-aging-drug-longevity-a27575f4",'
   'urlToImage: "https://images.wsj.net/im-772240/social",'
   'publishedAt:"2023-05-01T18:00:06Z",'
   'content:    "Can a Kidney Transplant Drug Keep You From Aging?A kidney transplant drug has become the latest fixation of people trying to fight aging.Some people looking to extend their lifespan have for years tu… [+828 chars]"}',
   200);
   });
     expect(newuser.length,1);
   
)}
```

Comment: First, [read the Mockito instructions and *follow them*](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito).  You have `class MockClient extends Mock implements GetApiData{}` but also `@GenerateMocks([MockClient])`.  Those make no sense to use together: the first approach was the old way before Dart null-safety; the current way uses code generation and requires adding an `import` for the generated `.mocks.dart` file.

Comment: Many people have migrated to Mocktail to avoid code generation but retain null safety and sound typing.